# How can I iterate a hashmap which contains a dto class as the value for the key?

Tags: java, excel, hashmap

I'm trying to get the values of the `keyset()` of a `hashmap` and print those into an excel sheet. And this is how my `hashmap` looks like:

```
public Map<String, CodaReportDTO> dateAndDTO = new HashMap<>(); //hashmap for date and the dto
```

So in the above, `CodaReportDTO` contains elements for a particular date. So I tried iterating the `hashmap keyset` like this in order to print the dates first:

```
    for (String dateKey : dateAndDTO.keySet()) { //dateAndDTO is the object

            Row tableDataRow = sheet.createRow(tableDataRowCount);
            Cell cell = tableDataRow.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(dateKey);
    }
```

So in order to iterate and get the values of a key (in other words, the values for the date), it should be either a `List` or a `Map`. How can I do this for a `hashmap` which contains a `DTO` class?

I have to do something like this but couldn't cast the class in to a `List`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> tableCellData = (List<Map<String, String>>) dateAndDTO.get(dateKey);
        for (Map<String, String> singleCellTableData : tableCellData) {
            int dateCellRef = dateCellReferences.get(singleCellTableData.keySet().iterator().next());
            Cell tableCell = tableDataRow.createCell(dateCellRef);
            tableCell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(singleCellTableData.values().iterator().next()));
        }
```

**EDIT**

The DTO class is available [here](http://pastebin.com/m5PNzVfN).

Where am I going wrong? Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Does `CodaReportDTO` implement `List<Map<String,String>>`? Or have any members that are that data type?

Comment: Plz show your CodaReportDTO class

Comment: @4castle nop it doesn't implement a `List`.

Comment: @mhasan i've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right , You need Something like this

```
public Map<String, CodaReportDTO> dateAndDTO = new HashMap<>(); //hashmap for date and the dto


Set<Entry<String, CodaReportDTO>> entrySet = dateAndDTO.entrySet();

for(Entry<String, CodaReportDTO> entry : entrySet){
    entry.getKey(); //your String key i.e. date in your case
    entry.getValue(); //your DTO value for this key
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, a life saver.:)

Answer (score 1):

You are having problem with you casting in below mentioned code

```
List<Map<String, String>> tableCellData = (List<Map<String, String>>) dateAndDTO.get(dateKey);
```

It should ideally be

```
CodaReportDTO tableCellData = (CodaReportDTO) dateAndDTO.get(dateKey);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Yes I somehow got it casted, but the problem I had was with the iteration.